# One ViewController calling delegated method of another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, delegation

I have a fairly simple app with three viewControllers. You can see them below:

[image: Storyboard]

I want both controllers to segue back to the splash screen after a set amount of time, but only as long as a user isn't interacting with the app. To do this I have them both conform to UITextFieldDelegate protocol so I can use a few different delegate functions to understand when the user interacts with text fields. Both viewControllers incorporate the following UITextFieldDelegate Functions, and both have a variable segueTimer that I reset every time a user interacts with a text field:

I'll try to post only code that is relevant to the issue.

**CheckInViewController**

```
class CheckInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkInView: CheckInView!

    var segueTimer: Timer?

    var fireTime = TimeInterval(20)

    var delegate: CheckInViewControllerDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad(){

        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkInView.searchTextField.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        resetSegueTimer()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
        //segueTimer?.invalidate()
        stopTimer()
    }


    func keyboardWillShow(sender: Notification){
        //print("keyboardWillShow()")

        ...

        resetSegueTime()
    }


    //This function fires everytime text changes
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        resetSegueTimer()

        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        resetSegueTimer()

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {


    }

    func resetSegueTimer(){

        stopTimer()
        startTimer()

    }

    func startTimer(){
        print("@CheckInVC  startTimer() \(segueTimer)")
        if segueTimer == nil{
            segueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: fireTime, target: self, selector: #selector(unwindToSplash), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
         }
    }

    func stopTimer(){
        print("@CheckInVC  stopTimer() \(segueTimer)")
        if segueTimer != nil {
            segueTimer!.invalidate()
            segueTimer = nil
        }
    }

    func unwindToSplash(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindViewControllers", sender: self)
    }

}
```

**CheckInViewControllerDelegate**

```
protocol CheckInViewControllerDelegate {
    var todaysGuests: NSMutableArray? { get set }
    var currentGuest: NSMutableDictionary? { get set }
    var guestRegisteredInKlik: Bool! { get set }
}
```

**RegisterViewController**

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController, CheckInViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var segueTimer: Timer?
    var fireTime = TimeInterval(20)

    var currentGuest: NSMutableDictionary?
    var todaysGuests: NSMutableArray?
    var guestRegisteredInKlik: Bool!

    @IBOutlet weak var registerView: RegisterVisitorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.registerView.companyTextField.delegate = self
        self.registerView.hostTextField.delegate = self
    {

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        registerView.nameLabel.text = ""
        registerView.companyTextField.text = ""
        registerView.hostTextField.text = ""

        stopTimer()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        resetSegueTimer()

    }


    //delegate method to differntiate between multiple textfields that have the VC as their delegate
    func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if textFieldToChange == self.registerView.companyTextField {
            resetSegueTimer()

            return true

        } else if textFieldToChange == self.registerView.hostTextField {
            resetSegueTimer()

            return true
        }

        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        resetSegueTimer()

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    func resetSegueTimer(){

        stopTimer()
        startTimer()

    }

    func startTimer(){
        print("@RegisterVC  startTimer() \(segueTimer)")
        if segueTimer == nil{
            segueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: fireTime, target: self, selector: #selector(unwindViewControllers), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

    func stopTimer(){
        print("@RegisterVC  stopTimer() \(segueTimer)")
        if segueTimer != nil {
            segueTimer!.invalidate()
            segueTimer = nil
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I am having involves the last two viewControllers, one of custom type CheckInViewController, and the other RegisterViewController. I have print statements in two delegated methods, textFielDidBeginEditing, one in each viewController. When I am in RegisterViewController and I switch to a different textfield, I see that the print statement of the textFieldDidBeginEditing function of the first viewController is called instead of the function of the viewController I am in.

The print statement just shows me the incorrect behavior. The actual problem is that the resetSegueTimer() function of the firstViewController is being called when I change textFields in the second viewController. Also, the textField(shouldChangeCharactersIn range: ) function called in the second viewController never invalidates the segueTimer in it's viewController, so the segue back to the splash isn't reset when a user edits the textfield.

I imagine this is an issue with me making two viewControllers conform to the same delegate protocol, while also making the second viewController the first viewController's delegate. But, I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Edit: Added keyBoardWillShow() function to CheckInViewController description, as it was contributing to the problem... that function was being called by RegisterViewController. Still not sure how, though.

Comment: Let me understand what you are trying to accomplish...when I timer expires in any ViewController you want to argue back to the splash viewController ?

Comment: First of all, delegate var should be weak reference.

Comment: @OverD Yes, when the timer expires I want to segue back to Splash, but I want that timer reset every time someone interacts with a textfield, giving the user time to enter text into the textfields. But let's say they walk away from the app, I want it to revert to the first viewController.

Comment: Create a custom class which confirms to uitextfielddelegate and set you timer logic in that class instead of repeating your code. Upon expiry of the timer set your splash viewcontroller as root view controller and navigate to it. Or you can embed your viewcontroller in a navigation view controller and pop it to root viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by removing resetSegueTimer() from keyboardWillShow() in first viewController. This had resetSegueTimer being called twice, once in keyboardWillShow and then again in EditingDidBegin, it was redundant. This function was also somehow being called by the second viewController when the keyboard would pop up... still not sure how that was possible.

I don't think this is the best fix for the application, and OverD gave a better solution. Will apply it eventually.